# Dynamic Parameter with 'and' Condition in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
where (((AccountTypeName = 'debit'  and (e.MerchantKey = 2)) 
or ((AccountTypeName = 'credit' and (e.MerchantKey = 3)))
```

Please let me know how to write a where condition in sql server with AccountTypeName as dynamic parameter with another 'and' condition.

```
if Account Typenam= debit then e.MerchentKey=2 
if Account Typename = credit then e.MerchentKey=3
```

This is wrong but this should do something like this

```
where AccountTypeName = ( @Market = 'debit' then e.MerchantKey = 2  )
```

Comment: If the value of `MerchantKey` is determined by `AccountTypeName`, then have a table that establishes this relationship, join to that table on `AccountTypeName` and have `and e.MerchantKey = that_table.MerchantKey`.

Comment: What doesn't work about the code at the top  of the question? And what exactly is meant by the third code block, I don't understand it

Comment: thank you for your response, but I don't have access to create tables . Can you please tell me if there is another way for this?

Comment: The third block is I need to make the AccountTypeName field dynamic, not sure how to write that with 'and' condition. @Market is dynamic parameter for AccountTypeName field

Comment: `and MerchantKey = case @Market when 'debit' then 2 when 'credit' then 3 end`?

Comment: Thanks GSreg, but how will sql server know that @Market value should be passed to the field AccountTypeName

Comment: Are you actually unable to combine `where AccountTypeName = @Market` and `and MerchantKey = case @Market when 'debit' then 2 when 'credit' then 3 end`, or is this a troll question?

Comment: this is not a troll question, thank you for the above statement. That works for me, but when parameter is null two values 2 and 3 should be passed, can I know how to write the else part with two values? where ((@Market is null) or (Market = @Market)) and a.MerchantKey =( case @Market when 'debit' then 2 when 'credit' then 3 else 2,3 end)

Comment: @GSerg, can you please let me know